# What is a good way to memoize data across many instances of a class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, object, instance, instance-variables, memoization

Consider: many instances of an object that generates data. It would be great to only generate that data once per run.

```
class HighOfNPeriods < Indicator
  def generate_data
    @indicator_data = DataStream.new
    (0..@source_data.data.count - 1).each do |i|
      if i < @params[:n_days]
      ...
      @indicator_data.add one_data
    end
  end
```

There are different instances of `HighOfNPeriods` with different `params` and different `@source_data`.

Here is how the indicator is used:

```
class Strategy
  attr_accessor :indicators

  def initialize params
    ...
  end
```

The method `HighOfNPeriods.generate_data` is called from within `Strategy`. Each `Strategy` gets a new instance of `HighOfNPeriods`, so it's not possible to pull it out as some kind of global value. Besides that, it should not be global.

`unless @indicator_data` wouldn't work because the data needs to be shared across many instances of `HighOfNPeriods`.

So, the question is:

```
What is a good way to memoize the instance variable `indicator_data` 
or the object `HighOfNPeriods` when there are many different instances, 
some of which have different data?
```

One solution is to store the data using ActiveRecord, but that's not really the way I want to do it at this time because:

1. Not all the generated data can be generated in advance because there are 
      too many permutations of params. It makes more sense to see if it has
      been generated before and then generate (and save) as necessary.
2. It doesn't take long to generate the data. It may be generated once and used 
      hundreds of times each run.
3. It will be faster to access the data from within the object than to pull it from the database.

Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Please note that it is very easy to implement memoization when your code is referential transparent. I'd say that your code is poorly designed, because your `generate_data` method is not accepting arguments needed to perform computations and depends on state of your object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a class variable `@@indicator_data` that is a hash with `[@params,@source_data]` as the key and the `@indicator_data` as the value. Then, at creation, do a memoization on `@@indicator_data[[@params,@source_data]]`.

```
class HighOfNPeriods < Indicator
  @@indicator_data = {}
  def generate_data
    @indicator_data = @@indicator_data[[@params, @source_data]] ||= DataStream.new
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: How does this work? `@params` is hash and `@source_data` is an object.

Comment: It does not matter what the key is. `@@indicator_data` stores a single instance of `DataStream.new` for each `[@params, @source_data]`. If there is already a `DataStream.new` stored in `@@indicator_data` for a particular `[@params, @source_data]`, then a new `DataStream.new` is not created.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't memoize it on instance level, go one level up and use class instance.

```
class Foo
  # I used *args here for simplicity of the example code.
  def generate_data *args
    if res = self.class.cache[args]
      puts "Data in cache for #{args.inspect} is #{res}"
      return res
    end

    puts "calculating..."
    p1, p2 = args
    res = p1 * 10 + p2
    self.class.cache[args] = res
    res
  end

  def self.cache
    @cache ||= {}
    @cache
  end
end


puts Foo.new.generate_data 1, 2 
puts Foo.new.generate_data 3, 4
puts Foo.new.generate_data 1, 2
# >> calculating...
# >> 12
# >> calculating...
# >> 34
# >> Data in cache for [1, 2] is 12
# >> 12
```

Comment: I really like this solution. And your explanation.I did not want to use a class variable and I feel better with the solution this helped me come up with to my particular problem.