# Alternate for action caching for normal gem ruby method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, rubygems

Lets take an example.

```
def get_data(param1,param2,param3)
  #do something
  #make some api calls
end
```

This method not belongs to controller. I am using this method in my ruby class in my gem.How to cache the result of method based on parameter coming.Something similar to action caching in rails comes with expiration ability.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good way to memoize data across many instances of a class in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552585/what-is-a-good-way-to-memoize-data-across-many-instances-of-a-class-in-ruby)

Comment: Also http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem/

Comment: memoize is a good suggestion but I have'nt put my whole code. It make some service calls inside so I need expiration time That why i want use caching.@BradWerth

Answer (score 3):

You can use this low level caching:

```
def competing_price
    Rails.cache.fetch("#{param1}-#{param2}-#{param3}", expires_in: 12.hours) do
      # do something.. 
    end
end
```

It has nothing related that you have to do it in controller or model only. you can use it anywhere else like your method.

Checkout the reference:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: I have already done this. But i kept this as an second option